# Updating the programme to make a CSV file in python

Tags: python, csv

I'm having some trouble with my code and I was woundering if someone could try and help. The trouble is (on python), is that when the user inputs a name for a csv file to create it. The csv file will only show after the programme has finished. I want to put something  in the csv however, because it hasn't been created yet I can't. 
here is my code...

```
import csv
def start():
   NewCSV = input('Name of csv: ')

   with open(NewCSV + '.csv', 'w') as myfile:
      wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

      Code_that_writes_in_CSV()

def Code_that_writes_in_CSV():
   print('') #Cant write this code because the file isn't created until the programme finishes
start()
```

If anyone could help to update the code while the programme is running it would be appreciated. :)

Comment: try to pass `wr` to `Code_that_writes_in_CSV` (as in `def Code_that_writes_in_CSV(wr): `) and then actually write something to `wr`. the last comment in your code does not make much sense...

Comment: Are you saying that using a context manager doesn't create the file when you open in write mode? I can't test right now but I really doubt this conclusion. I think you've misdiagnosed the problem.

Comment: You are creating a file descriptor and exiting. What are you expecting more than what you observe (an empty file after the program quits)...?

Comment: @Lorenzo , yeh I'm expecting an empty csv file with the name of the csv that the user inputted. It does do that however it does it when the program ends, which is inconvenient for the next part of the code that I want to write

Comment: @T.James sorry what is happening is not inconvenient, it is what *should* happen. See the answer below if you want to fill the file. I wrote *should* because depending on the OS and on the way file are bufferized between RAM and disk, there could be some timelapse - but nothing shows you are in this case, am I right?

Comment: @Lorenzo Okay. You are right. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code which wants to write needs to access the value of the variable `wr` somehow. You don't tell us what that code really wants to do, but as a starting point, here is one way to modify your example.

```
import csv

def start():
    NewCSV = input('Name of csv: ')

    with open(NewCSV + '.csv', 'w') as myfile:
        wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        Code_that_writes_in_CSV(wr)

def Code_that_writes_in_CSV(handle):
    handle.writerow([''])
```

A more common arrangement is to keep all the CSV handling in a single function, and perhaps perform some calculations in a separate function.

```
def write_to_csv(filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as myfile:
        wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        for row in code_that_calculates_a_row_at_a_time():    
            wr.writerow(row)
```

The code which calculates a row at a time could `return` a list of rows, or usefully `yield` a single row at a time.

Comment: You mean with `snake_case` in the function names? Yeah, I didn't think much about that but it's worth pointing out as well.